# inserting data into temp table based on whether it exists in db

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting data from a table `table1` into a temp table. I am unsure whether it will be in `db1` or `db2` (this script is reused a lot). I want to check of the existence of it in `db1` if its there create the temp table in `db1` and if not create it in `db2`
my script is as follows

```
drop table if exists ##temp  

if object_id('[db1].[dbo].[table1]') is not null             
begin
    select *
    into ##temp           
    from [db1].[dbo].[table1]             
end             
else             
begin   
    drop table if exists ##temp

    select *
    into ##temp        
    from [db2].[dbo].[table1]            
end
```

however, while both the select into queries work individually I get this error when I run the whole block

> There is already an object named '##temp' in the database.

It seems to trigger the else statement even when it is not required

Comment: Temp tables ALL are created in tempdb. In your case they are global temp tables. Is there a reason you need global temp tables? They are truly awful to work with and cause all sorts of issues. Also, why do you think you need to drop the global temp table before the IF statement and then again inside of the else? If it had existed before the else it would already be dropped.

Comment: no no reason why I need global temp tables but I was hoping that would mean I wouldnt get the 'There is already an object named '##temp' in the database.' error. I would prefer to use a regular temp table. I only want to drop the table at the start but no matter the result of the if statement the error was being thrown that the temp table already existed.

Comment: The problem here is essentially that the parser detects that two `SELECT INTO` are creating the table. So it throws an error at compile time. This is one reason why it's best to just do proper `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: @Charlieface yea I think youre right, ended up just using a python conditional to control where it looks.

Answer (score 1):

I think they need to be executed in separate batches.
Try it like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[db1].[dbo].[table1]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = N'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##temp;';
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = N'SELECT *
    INTO ##temp
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1]; ';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = N'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##temp;';
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = N'
    SELECT *
    INTO ##temp
    FROM [db2].[dbo].[table1]; ';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the instance of global temp table exists for all sessions, most likely scenario  is another user creating temp table with same name while you are executing only portion of the above query before other session ends.

FYI: it is not triggering else statement based on your error, if statement is being executed multiple times without checking if `##temp` table exists. try executing `drop table if exists ##temp`  inside if statement

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[db1].[dbo].[table1]') IS NOT NULL             
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE IF exists ##temp  
    SELECT *
    INTO ##temp           
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1]             
END             
ELSE             
BEGIN   
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##temp

    SELECT *
    INTO ##temp              
    FROM [db2].[dbo].[table1]            
END
```

Comment: still get same error